# How to convert Javascript quiz to show a button after a a combination of buttons are chosen

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to figure out how to change this code around so that when someone answers certain questions, they will get certain a certain link or button depending on the combination of questions asked. I prefer to use javascript and HTML because that's all I know.

```
<html>
<head>

<style type="text/css">
<!--
.bgclr {background-color: white; color: black; font-weight: bold;}
-->
</style>

<script language="JavaScript">

 This script and many more are available free online at 
 The JavaScript Source!! http://www.javascriptsource.com 

<!-- Begin
// Insert number of questions
var numQues = 4;

// Insert number of choices in each question
var numChoi = 3;

// Insert number of questions displayed in answer area
var answers = new Array(4);

// Insert answers to questions
answers[0] = "Cascading Style Sheets";
answers[1] = "Dynamic HTML";
answers[2] = "Netscape";
answers[3] = "Common Gateway Interface";

// Do not change anything below here ...
function getScore(form) {
var score = 0;
var currElt;
var currSelection;
for (i=0; i<numQues; i++) {
currElt = i*numChoi;
for (j=0; j<numChoi; j++) {
  currSelection = form.elements[currElt + j];
  if (currSelection.checked) {
    if (currSelection.value == answers[i]) {
      score++;
      break;
    }
  }
}
}
score = Math.round(score/numQues*100);
form.percentage.value = score + "%";
var correctAnswers = "";
for (i=1; i<=numQues; i++) {
correctAnswers += i + ". " + answers[i-1] + "\r\n";
}
form.solutions.value = correctAnswers;
}
//  End -->
</script>


</head>
<body>    

<h3>Web Design Quiz</h3>

<form name="quiz">
1.  What does CSS stand for?
<ul style="margin-top: 1pt">
<li><input type="radio" name="q1" value="Colorful Style Symbols"/>Colorful Style  
Symbols</li>
<li><input type="radio" name="q1" value="Cascading Style Sheets"/>Cascading Style    
Sheets</li>
<li><input type="radio" name="q1" value="Computer Style Symbols"/>Computer Style  
Symbols</li>
</ul>

2. What does DHTML stand for?
<ul style="margin-top: 1pt">
<li><input type="radio" name="q2" value="Dramatic HTML"/>Dramatic HTML</li>
<li><input type="radio" name="q2" value="Design HTML"/>Design HTML</li>
<li><input type="radio" name="q2" value="Dynamic HTML"/>Dynamic HTML</li>
</ul>
3. Who created Javascript?
<ul style="margin-top: 1pt">
<li><input type="radio" name="q3" value="Microsoft"/>Microsoft</li>
<li><input type="radio" name="q3" value="Netscape"/>Netscape</li>
<li><input type="radio" name="q3" value="Sun Micro Systems"/>Sun Micro Systems</li>
</ul>
4. What does CGI stand for?
<ul style="margin-top: 1pt">
<li><input type="radio" name="q4" value="Cascading Gate Interaction"/>Cascading Gate   
Interaction</li>
<li><input type="radio" name="q4" value="Common GIF Interface"/>Common GIF 
Interface</li>
<li><input type="radio" name="q4" value="Common Gateway Interface"/>Common Gateway 
Interface</li>
</ul>

<input type="button" value="Get score" onClick="getScore(this.form)"/>
<input type="reset" value="Clear answers"/>
<p> Score = <strong><input class="bgclr" type="text" size="5" name="percentage"  
disabled="disabled"/></strong><br/><br/>
Correct answers:<br/>
<textarea class="bgclr" name="solutions" wrap="virtual" rows="4" cols="30"    
disabled="disabled">
</textarea>
</p></form>


</body>


</html>`
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ThqmR/

Comment: Added the JSFiddle for you. Have you tried this yourself? Can you post any attempt you have made? If you just want a button to appear if they get 100% correct, then `if (score === 100) { Object.style.visibility="visible"; }` should do the trick

Comment: There are some problems already: You don't have a doctype, you close the head for a second time (just before closing the HMTL tag), you have comments in your JavaScript but you can't do that in this way.

Comment: Have a look at: http://jsfiddle.net/3XgZu/

Comment: @MarkWylde I'm very new and I have tried for a while but they just get totally messed up. I'm new and learning. I want is so that it doesn't give me a score or show correct answers. What I want the form to do is show a button when a certain line of questions are answered. If a question is changed then it will show a different link inside of the button.

Comment: @putvande I will fix that. Mistakes happen but can you maybe help me?

Comment: 1999 called, they want their DHTML back.